# Why do you say "Second to none" (the best) when "Next to nothing" (means worthless)

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I saw this question [What does "For next to nothing" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74708/what-does-for-next-to-nothing-mean?rq=1) and it got me thinking about "The man with the golden gun" lyrics.

> An assassin that's second to none

If you think about it, none is the worst possible, because none is nothing, so second to none should be (in my opinion) almost the worst ever

What do you guys think?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Please note that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and questions that solicit opinions or thoughts are explicitly off-topic. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance. The short answer is that *second to none* means *unsurpassed*; K2 is second to Mount Everest, but Everest is second to none.

Comment: Think of the word *none* as *nobody*. Therefore, *second to none* really means *second to nobody*. In other words, you are the first which in turn means that you are the best.

Comment: Right, you da man. [just a bit of levity.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something or someone is "second to none" that means there is no-one or nothing better. It takes second place to nobody/nothing.

> second to none ​ as good as or better than all others:
>
> The conditions that these prisoners are kept in are second to none.

[Second to none (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/second-to-none)